# How to root the Motorola Droid Razr?

Tags: rooting, motorola-droid-razr

How do I root my Motorola Droid Razr?

Comment: I cannot answer your question, but I edited it so it can be found, and also added it to our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575). You might want to follow that link meanwhile, and check for related phones and other mentioned methods. With some luck, you already find something there. It would further help to update your question with some more details on your device, such as e.g. Android version, Baseband version. This is important for finding a suitable method.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0JA8TKNWTEk it's in spanish, but you can find similar tutorials in your language :)

Comment: I used KingRoot. You can download it from the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app, called framaroot. You can [download it from XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2128511&d=1374257608). It's working with XT919 and XT910 (I installed in a razr D3 XT919).

There is also a video tutorial in youtube [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WZBb4W0-ds)

Answer (score 1):

I used iRoot, it worked for me but installs Kinguser as the SuperSU app, still worked though.
Best of all it uses no PC.

Link: http://www.mgyun.com/m/en